# PHP: Find the exact position of a key in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a dynamic multidimensional array with unique keys in all dimensions. (**Array keys can be anything**, below array is just an example to show that all keys are unique.)

```
$data = array(
'0' => array(
    '0-0' => array(
        '0-0-0' => array(
            '0-0-0-0' => 'some value',
            '0-0-0-1' => 'some value',
            ),
        '0-0-1' => array(
            '0-0-1-0' => 'some value',
            '0-0-1-1' => 'some value',
            '0-0-1-2' => 'some value',
            ),
        '0-0-2' => array(
            '0-0-2-0' => 'some value',
            '0-0-2-1' => 'some value',
            ),
        '0-0-3' => array(
            '0-0-3-0' => 'some value',
            ),
        ),
    '0-1' => array(
        '0-1-0' => array(
            '0-1-0-0' => 'some value',
            '0-1-0-1' => 'some value',
            ),
        '0-1-1' => array(
            '0-1-1-0' => 'some value',
            '0-1-1-1' => 'some value',
            ),
        '0-1-2' => array(
            '0-1-2-0' => 'some value',
            '0-1-2-1' => 'some value',
            ),
        ),
    ),
'1' => 'some value',
'2' => array(
    '2-0' => 'some value',
    '2-1' => array(
        '2-1-0' => 'some value',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Depth and count of sub-arrays are dynamic. All keys are unique, but they don't have a pattern as the above example.

I need to find the exact position (with all parents hierarchically) of a given key in this array. For example;

`get_key_position('0-1-2-1', $data);` should return `array('0', '0-1', '0-1-2', '0-1-2-1')`
`get_key_position('2-1-0', $data);` should return `array('2', '2-1', '2-1-0')`
`get_key_position('1', $data);` should return `array('1')`

Comment: Why not storing the keys as one per level? For example, key 0-1-2-1 would be `$array[0][1][2][1]`. Moreover, since your key already has a dimensional level by itself, you can store this all in a single array. Repeating data is always a sign that something can be improved.

Comment: @sidyll keys don't have to be like "0-1-2-1". That was just an example to show that all keys are unique. I edited the the question to clarify that.

Comment: I see. Sorry, I got your problem wrong. Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038137/retrieve-all-parent-keys-of-a-given-child-key-in-array

Comment: Hi. I'm a little confused - to take your last example, since it's the most straightforward - do you want `get_key_position('1', $data)` to literally return `[1]`, or the value at `$data[1]`; i.e: `some value`?

Comment: @DarraghEnright, `get_key_position('1', $data)` should return only `array('1')` so I can understand that it is a key of a first level element.

Comment: @sidyll, The answer of that question is very close to what I want. I only need to add the subject key itself to the return array. Thanks!

Comment: So you're just trying to generate the combination of keys from the given string; e.g: `1` returns `[1]`; `1-2` returns `[1, 1-2]` and so on?

Comment: Something like this in other words? https://eval.in/599661

Comment: @DarraghEnright, As I mentioned in the question, array keys can be anything. The array in the question is just an example to show that all keys are unique. The keys don't have to be like `'1'`, `'1-2'`, `'1-2-3'`. They can be `'apple'`, `'banana'`, `'pear'` etc.

Comment: I understand that - but given a particular string, separated by hypens - is your question that you want to return the combinations of that string, e.g: `foo-bar-baz` becomes `[foo, foo-bar, foo-bar-baz]`? This is how I read your question - however I have a feeling we're missing something here because you want to pass the `$data` array into the `get_key_position()` function that you want to create. The reason why is somewhat lost on me - perhaps you can clarify?

Comment: The array could be like this: http://hastebin.com/suzopaxewi.coffee In this example, `get_key_position('lemon', $data);` should return `array('apple', 'banana', 'pear', 'lemon')`. I want to pass the $data array to the get_key_position() function, because the key (first paremeter of the function) should be searched in the $data array. Anyway, this answer seems to be enough for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12038556/3084708

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't make the effort to go and look at the different links cited by comments under your question, so maybe I'm re-inventing the wheel :)

Anyway, this seems to work in any situation:

```
function look4key($key, $data, $path = []) {
  if (is_array($data)) {
    foreach ($data AS $localKey => $value) {
      $localKey = (string)$localKey;
      $localPath = array_merge($path, [$localKey]);
      if ($localKey == $key) {
        return $localPath;
      }
      if ($nestedPath = look4key($key, $value, $localPath)) {
        return $nestedPath;
      }
    }
  }
  # returns NULL if $key not found
}
```

Hope it's rather self-explanatory, except this pitfall: `(string)$localKey` is needed for keys like `'0'`, `'1'`, etc, because of this automatic cast (look at [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)):

> Strings containing valid integers will be cast to the integer type. E.g. the key "8" will actually be stored under 8.